# Universal app detect start focus lost

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I am writing a universal app for WP8.1 I don't want it to suspend.

Some banking apps are like this.  If a banking app is running and I click the back button or the start button, the app does not get suspended.  It exits.  I suppose the developers do not want bank account credentials hanging about in state data.

I am trying to do the same for my secure-messaging app.  I can put an event on the back button:

```
Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
```

and inside this event handler call:

```
App.Current.Exit();
```

This works.

But how do I detect if the app loses focus from the user pressing the start button, search button or off button?

I have tried this event in the App class:

Window.Current.Activated += Current_Activated;

and this function, also in the App class:

protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)

but neither of them are called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```cs
public sealed partial class App : Application
{
    /* --- Omitted generated code here --- */

    protected override void OnWindowCreated(WindowCreatedEventArgs args)
    {
        args.Window.VisibilityChanged += Window_VisibilityChanged;
    }

    void Window_VisibilityChanged(object sender, VisibilityChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.Visible)
            Exit();
    }
}
```